# os.mkdir() and os.makedirs() fail to create directory inside /tmp yet no exception is raised

Tags: python, exception, ros, tmp

Using **Python 2.7** on 32bit **Xubuntu 14.04 LTS**

I'm struggling with this issue for two days now. So far I have tried using `umask`, `chmod` and what not. The results is always the same - failure to create a directory.

Here is a snippet from my application:

```
def checkRootDirExists(self):
    '''
    Check if the process folder is present and create it if not
    '''
    if not exists(self.dir_name): # Using os.path.exists()
      rospy.loginfo('SR2: Process directory "%s" doesn\'t exist and therefore will be created', (self.dir_name+'/'))
      try:
        mkdir(self.dir_name)
      except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
          rospy.logerr('Directory exists')
        elif e.errno != errno.EACCES:
          rospy.logerr('Access violation')
        else:
          rospy.logerr('Something else happened')
    else:
      rospy.loginfo('SR2: Process directory "%s" already exists', (self.dir_name+'/'))
```

**Note:** rospy is part of the Python API of ROS (Robot Operating System). You can view it as a simple `print()` statement (it's basically exactly that but has the formatting of `printf()` from C/C++).

The output is as follows:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1455985284.031136] SR2: Process directory "/tmp/rosrunlttalkerpy/" doesn't exist and therefore will be created
```

**Note:** Don't forget that the `/` at the end is only added for the output. Internally it is `/tmp/rosrunlttalkerpy`

I have added the exception cases separately just to see where the problem is coming from. The thing is...No exception gets raised hence none of the print statements are displayed. This wouldn't be a problem if the folder actually was created which is not the case here. I have tried the generic way of handling an exception using `except Exception` along with several other more specific error types that I thought might give me some feedback. Same result - nothing.

My `self.dir_name` is an automatically generated string using things like launch command (`roslaunch`, `rosrun` etc.), package and node name. I have made sure that it's a valid string. As an example the following is one of the values I generate:

```
# launch command: rosrun
# package: lt
# node: listener.py
/tmp/rosrunltlistenerpy
```

My user has `sudo` privileges however in this case this is not important since:

- I run my ROS in normal user space
- The **write** and **read** permissions to `/tmp` even though owned by `root` are okay for all three types of users (`owner`, `group` and `others`).

At first I thought that there was something fishy going on with `/tmp` itself. However I have also tried `~` yet the result is the same - no error, no directory.

The next thing I thought I might try is to use the interactive interpreter. So I started it and used `mkdir()` with the same path as in my code above. A directory was created!

```
>>> dir_name = '/tmp/rosrunltlistenerpy'
>>> if exists(dir_name): print('Dir exists!')
... else:
...   try:
...     mkdir(dir_name)
...   except OSError as e:
...     print('Something went wrong')

RESULT: rosrunltlistenerpy directory created inside /tmp
```

Further I have another function called `cleanup()` which basically removes the created directory along with all files in it.

```
def cleanup(self):
    '''
    Removes all files related to the external process: .proc, .bash and root directory containing these two files
    '''
    try:
      # Sometimes rmtree may fail
      rmtree(self.dir_name)
    except:
      # in which case we can simply remove the separate files one by one
      try:
        remove(self.proc_path)
        remove(self.bash_path)
        rmdir(self.dir_name)
      except:
        if self.bash_pid or self.proc_pid:
          self.proc_status = ProcStatus.FAILED_STOP
        self.statusSignal.emit(self.proc_status)
```

The funny thing is that this actually works. So for some reason creation of a directory from withing my application fails SILENTLY yet deleting of that same directory (if I have created it externally like when using the interactive interpreter) works fine. This makes no sense at all. Any ideas what might be the reason for this strange behaviour?

**EDIT2:**

I have added a print (in my case `loginfo()`) right after `mkdir()` inside the `try`'s body and it appears on the screen. This would mean that indeed no exception is raised.

Comment: Do you keep your application running long enough? Could it be that your cleanup function has already deleted the directory before you can even see it appearing?

Comment: Not possible. The creation of the directory is done inside the constructor of my `QObject`. It is done again (in case meanwhile someone has deleted it) when a `start signal` is received. In addition I have a slot in my `QObject` which gets triggered ever 10ms and also runs `checkRootDirExists()` in order to make sure that the directory is present. The `cleanup` is only triggered when a `stop signal` is received. It is not even triggered when I close my application since I want to use the data stored in the files inside that directory to restore the application's state upon relaunch.

Comment: "os.mkdir() and os.makedirs() fail to create directory inside /tmp yet no exception is raised" - *don't make silly assumptions*, you'll end up chasing ghosts.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath This was...helpful? Would be nice if you maybe write how to see if no exception is raised or not. -_- I have also tried `except Exception` along with multiple other more specific error-types without any result.

Comment: The code you provide here looks fine for me. Therefore, without the rest so we can try it out ourselves (which admittedly might be a bit complicated), we'll have to do troubleshooting. That involves a lot of iterative q&a and Stackoverflow is not suited for that. You better go asking in SO's python chat or at freenode's #python channel.

Comment: Will give the chat a shot I guess.

Comment: What does the actual log entry say? Any chance the running app is using a different directory (perhaps based on environment variables). _"'SR2: Process directory "%s" doesn\'t exist and therefore will be created'"_ should be in there somewhere.

Comment: I've edited my post. The directory that the application is using (or to be more precise - the `QObject` that is part of it) is taken from a configuration file and generated automatically. No environment variables are taken into account for this procedure.

Comment: @rbaleksandar: you're still thinking in terms of that silly assumption. you're almost certainly wrong. there's nothing wrong with those OS calls. http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/ to begin with, it's unclear why you think the directory isn't created.

Comment: When did I ever say that Python is broken? I am trying to figure out what *I am doing wrong*. Your comments here is utterly pointless. If you have nothing constructive to contribute to the solution of this problem simply don't post anything. If you have visited the chat you might have seen that we have been discussing my situation here.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the directory is being deleted after being created. Or maybe your application is running with a different root directory (e.g. via chroot or via LXC or whatever). Try tracing your program. For example, try `strace -e trace=mkdir,rmdir python myscript.py`

Comment: It's quite difficult to use `strace` with ROS (I am actually using `roslaunch` to start my application). However I am now close to a solution. It is Qt signal related along with the working directory of the detached process (which writes to the directory) along with the thread I am using to create the directory itself.

Comment: If you can't trace, you can watch `/tmp` for changes using a tool like [inotifywatch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch)

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try. Right now I am basically calling `ls /tmp` all the time. LOL

Comment: Did you check wheter this is specific to the `/tmp/`-subdirs? It might be the case that dirs created there are only visible to the creating process.

Comment: As I've mentioned it seems that there is some bad event handling in my application resulting in triggering the `mkdir()` to a much later point of time. I have to see how to handle this situation properly. As for the visibility - nope, the folder (once created) is visible to me (using Thunar and also inside multiple shells I have opened).

Comment: Your code *works*. If no exception is raised, the directory *has been created*. Some other assumption is wrong here.

Comment: Please read my comments above. Yes, the directory is created however due to the amount of events that need to be processed this happens much later.